# Upload email from nnml to Gmail (or IMAP)

Tags: email, mutt, imap, gmail

I have just found some tens of thousands of old emails in a Linux subdirectory which I would like to upload to GMail.   GMail has an IMAP interface, so if your answer is IMAP-specific, that's perfectly fine.

The emails are stored in [nnml format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Spool.html) which is sequentially numbered files, one per message.   They are not mbox files (that is, there is no "^From " line at the top of the file and therefore no need to escape that in the body).  I think these emails were originally written there by either Mutt or Gnus (very likely both, at various times).

What programs (or libraries) exist that do this?

Comment: Interesting. Mind showing us the code you've written so far?

Comment: None, so far, for this problem.

Comment: It seems there are several utilities to upload mail to gmail from files in mbox format, such as the mail client thunderbird, and others mentioned at the end of [this](https://commons.lbl.gov/display/itfaq/Google+TakeOut). I don't know the nnml format, but if it is plain text with no binary and starts with headers, it may be as simple as concatenating the files, adding a dummy `From ...` line between them, and a blank line at the end of each, and replace `From ` at the start of any line with `>From `.

Comment: Some [se] sites consider software recommendations to be off-topic but this site has a specific tag for it, [tag:software-rec]. I voted to re-open this question but I'd recommend re-tagging the question. If no such software exists, it would be an interesting programming project.